# How to redirect subdomain to main domain maintaining the same URL?

Tags: php, apache, url, .htaccess, subdomain

My main domain(www.mysite.com) is pointing to a folder in my server (/home/user_name/htdocs/mysite.com).

I have recently created a subdomain(m.mysite.com) through my hosting account. But it is pointing it to a new folder (/home/user_name/htdocs/m.mysite.com) in my server. I am not able to edit the path to which this new subdomain points to. All my files are hosted in my main folder path.

My Requirement -

When a user visits m.mysite.com he should be redirected to mysite.com **but the URL in the browser should still say m.mysite.com**
I'm handling the mobile view by detecting the subdomain using $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']

Comment: `I am not able to edit the path to which this new subdomain points to.` tells me its an ISP problem as there's no reason for this. Contact them.

Comment: Since I am on a free hosting account, they do not allow me to edit that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should able to write an .htaccess file with this rule, provided it is the same user and has read permisssions to both URLs:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) ../mysite.com/$1 [L]
```

Or, you can make a symlink to the main site, let's say:

```
./mysite.com
    dirs and folders

./m.mysite.com
    drwxr-xr-x main_site -> ../mysite.com
```

And an htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/?mysite\.com 404.html [L] # Do not show the real filesystem layer
RewriteRule (.*) ./mysite.com/$1 [L]
```

Comment: I tried this - RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) ../mysite.com/$1 [L]

Comment: But it says, 400 Bad request
Bad Request

Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand.

Comment: Try the last one if you can… I can't setup a configuration like that right now

Comment: Within `/path/to/m.mysite.com`, type `ln -s ../mysite.com main_site` if you are on almost any UNIX-like shell.

Comment: Nope. I do not have access to that. I have only ftp access.

Comment: Have you tried the first rule without the `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^m\.mysite\.com` ? IDK why is it a 400 Bad Request

Answer (score 1):

Try creating an index.html file in the root directory of m.mysite.com subdomain with the iframe code below.
(Use "mysite.com" where you see "example.com"; StackOverflow won't let me use mysite.com).

```html
<iframe
  src="https://www.example.com"
  style="
    position: fixed;
    top: 0px;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    border: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    z-index: 999999;
    height: 100%;
  ">
</iframe>
```

Comment: No... the correct way is using redirection (as per other answers).  Simply creating a frame is very much a deprecated approach.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could set up an htaccess file under m.mysite.com with a RewriteRule that points all requests to a different URL.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.mysite.com/$1
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. With that .htaccess, the URL in the browser changes to www.mysite.com. But I want the browser to show m.mysite.com so that I can detect this subdomain inside my web app and show mobile views accordingly

Comment: This rewrite rule would result in a redirect.  Maybe this would be a good answer with the `[P]` (proxy) flag on the rule.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to be doing it.

Get a proper plugin for mobile sites like WP-Touch or MobilePress, and do a mobile specific theme. You don't need to be mucking around with htaccess ot httpd.conf files for this bit.

Answer (score -1):

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} .
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^m.mysite\.com
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.mysite.com/$1 [R=301, L]
```

Comment: This explicitly calls for a redirect, the question was how to do it without a redirect.